# Sort 2D objects spirally from the center, the fastest way to do it?

Tags: algorithm

Given a screen of XY size, also given an unsorted array of 2D objects of size n located on this screen (stored point xy coordinates - the middle of this object aka std::pair<float, float>), you need to output the coordinates of first k objects in spiral order, as indicated in the figure (mb some order is wrong, just example). What is the fastest algorithm to do this? A simple description of such an algorithm will suffice for answer to me.

There is an idea to sort these objects in relation to the size of the angles between the center point of the screen and the point of the 2D object (the larger the angle, the farther the object is), but it seems that there may be a better option!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `r` the radial distance between two successive levels of the spiral, ie the increase in distance from the centre after a full turn around the centre along the spiral.

Represent each box by its polar coordinates `(d, a)`, where `d` is distance from the centre and `a` is (clockwise?) angle between the horizontal axis, the centre and the box.

### First idea

Then sort with respect to the following inequality:

```
(d1, a1) < (d2, a2) iff:
    d1 + r <= d2                    // the boxes are on different spiral levels
    or |d1 - d2| < r and a1 < a2.   // the boxes are on same spiral level but have different angles
```

It's far from perfect and you might want to consider other ways to combine `d` and `a` to define the spiral more properly.

### Second idea

- Map each point `(d, a)` to the closest point `(d', a)` which is exactly on the spiral;
- Sort by increasing `d'`.

The spiral consists in points that satisfy the equation `d = r (a + 2 k pi) / (2 pi)` for any nonnegative k.

Finding the closest point `(d', a)` which is exactly on the spiral can be achieved by rounding `d`:

```
d' := round((d - (a / (2 pi))) / r) * r + (a / (2 pi))
```

(The formula above assumes 0 <= a < 2 pi.)